# Is there a way to attach a baby gate to my outdoor wall without drilling into the wood?

Tags: walls

The top of the stairs is a steel railing and a wooden wall. I don’t want to damage the wood but as this is at the top of stairs I can’t use a pressure mounted gate. Can I somehow build a temporary wall and drill into that? But how would that wall stay safely upright? Would strong adhesive tape hold up a strip of wood to drill into? But I imagine the elements would weaken the r adhesive and sometimes removing it can damage the wall anyway.

Note- I bought a strip of wood and clamp to attach one end to the steel railing.

[image]

Comment: It's a bit difficult to see what's going on in those two very small pictures. If you would [edit] in larger pics, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is, most likely, going to be to mount the gate to the wall, even if that means putting a hole in the siding.

I'm willing to bet that if you were to walk around your house, you'd see lots of outside things mounted to the house, right through the siding, from the numbers on the front of the house to your electric meter, shutters (if you have them) and other random decorative bits stuck to the house.

To protect the house, after you drill the pilot hole for the mounting screws, put a little dab of clear silicone caulk into the holes, the put each mounting plate in place and run the screws through the mounting plate holes and the caulk and into the house. The caulk will help prevent water infiltration.

Comment: The screw will also prevent water infiltration. :)

Answer (score 1):

A gate could be hung from the railing as illustrated below.

[image]

A block of wood maybe plywood or wide dimensional lumber (2x6 or 8 maybe) could be attached to the railing with clamp or strap hardware. Electrical conduit or pipe hanger straps would do. Or, put a second piece of wood on the opposite side of the railing and bolt or screw through the gaps in the railing from one wood block to the other.

Mount the gate to the wood block with hinges. Ordinary door hinges could work but there are other styles too such as continuous "piano" hinge, offset hinges, etc.

The parts can be arranged so that the gate won't open toward the stairs -- it'll bind instead. It'll only open outward, away from the stairs. You can then block it being pulled open with patio furniture, a rope or rigid strut attached on the stairway side of the gate, etc. (Obviously, the size and strength of the parts must be matched to their opponent, whether an infant, toddler, or larger child who might defeat the gate so a young sibling can go through..)

Consider small fingers and pinch points around the hinge. Here are some ideas to help prevent squished fingers:

- continuous hinge prevents a gap opening on one side of the hinge
- solid paneling can prevent an arm and hand reaching around to the back side of the hinge

This arrangement will put a fair amount of strain on the edge of the baby gate. Many of the off-the-shelf gates I've seen may not be up to the task. You might do well to just buy a full sheet of plywood or MDF at a home center, cut it yourself or ask them to do it on the in-store panel saw, and make a full DIY project of it!

Comment: This is a great suggestion! I wouldn't think that any extra wood would be necessary here - simply drill holes through the post, treat to help prevent rust, and run bolts w/washers into nuts on the other side.